# An equality for the reduced homology related to the comparability graph of a poset

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, graph-theory, posets, simplicial-complexes

$\DeclareMathOperator\width{width}$Let $P$ be a finite poset with $n$ elements (we can assume that $P$ is connected and has width at most $n-2$). The **comparability graph** $G_P=(V,E)$ associated to $P$ is by definition the finite graph with vertices $V=P$ and two elements $v, w \in V$ are adjacent if $v<w$ or $w<v$.
A subset $S$ of $V$ is called a **dominating set in $G$** if every vertex $v$ in $G$ belongs to $S$ or is adjacent to an element of $S$.

The **dominance complex $D(G_P)$** is the simplicial complex consisting of the subsets of $V$ whose complements are dominating. We look at homology of such a simplicial complex over fields here (see [Perkinson - Homology of Simplicial Complexes](http://people.reed.edu/%7Edavidp/411/handouts/simplicial.pdf) for a definition).

> Question (Formulation 1): Is it true that the first degree in which the reduced homology is non-zero of $D(G_P)$ is equal to $n-1-\width(P)$?

(Here $\width(P)$ denotes the maximal cardinality of an antichain in the poset $P$.)

By theorem 1 in [Matsushita - Dominance complex and vertex cover number](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.04145), we should have that the first non-zero degree of the reduced homology is less than or equal to $n-1-\width(P)$. And the question asks whether we have equality in theorem 1 of the previous article in the case of graphs given as comparability graphs of finite posets.

Here is a more direct alternative formulation of the problem:

Let $P$ be a finite poset  with $n$ elements (we can assume that $P$ is connected and the width of $P$ is at most $n-2$). For $p \in P$ set  $J(p):=\{q \in P \mid p \nleq q \}$ and $I(p):= \{ q \in P \mid q \leq p \}$. For a subset $S \subseteq P$ set $J(S) := \bigcap\limits_{p \in S}{J(p)}$ and
$I(S):= \bigcup\limits_{p \in S}{I(p)}$.

Then the simplicial complex $\Gamma(P)$ associated to $P$ is defined by the condition
$S \in \Gamma(P)$ if and only if $J(S^c) \subseteq I(S^c)$.

> Question (Formulation 2): Is it true that the first non-zero positive degree of the homology of $\Gamma(P)$ appears at $n-1-\width(P)$?

The question is tested with a computer and true for all posets with at most 10 elements (thus for nearly 3 million examples).

(Background: The original formulation of the question is Formulation 2 and the connection to the article [Matsushita - Dominance complex and vertex cover number](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.04145) was noted by Hugh Thomas.)

Comment: Comparability graphs are a subclass of perfect graphs. Have you considered if the equality holds for all perfect graphs?

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks for the comment. The problem comes from homological algebra of incidence algebras of posets, so I have not studied the problem when there might be equality for a more general class of graphs yet. I might do some tests later related to perfect graphs.

Comment: @SamHopkins I think I found a counterexample for perfect graphs using Sage, see the answer below (I posted it as a community wiki answer as it is too long for a comment and also does not fit well into the question).

Comment: Trivial remark: if this bound is attained for _all_ fields $k$, then there must be a _free_ summand in the integral homology in the bottom degree. In the connected examples that you've checked, is there _just_ one free summand, or is the bottom homology larger? If there's just the one free summand, then you might next ask whether some kind of Poincare duality holds... Also, to be sure I'm following properly: we have that $S \in \Gamma(P)$ if and only if there does not exist $x \in P$ such that $\{p \in P \mid p \leq x \vee x \leq p\} \subseteq S$, right?

Comment: This is the combinatorial Alexander dual of the simplicial complex with simplices the non-dominating sets in the sense of https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1172. Proving there is no homology beneath the given dimension is equivalent to proving there is no cohomology of the Alexander dual above dimension $\mathrm{width}(P)-2$. 
This might be helpful: one can hope to prove the conjecture by exhibiting a homotopy equivalence to a complex of dimension $w-2$. Also, over a field it is enough to show $H_i=0$ for $i\ge w-1$. Perhaps this gives a more intuitive picture.

Comment: Have you tried a poset where every vertex is contained in at least two distinct maximal antichains?

Comment: @GevaYashfe Thank you for that comment. Is there an easy way to check whether it might be homotopy equivalent to a complex of dimension $w-2$ using a computer program like Sage?

Comment: @Mare Perhaps the simplest tool for attempting computations like this mechanically is discrete Morse theory. I don't know if there is a Sage implementation. If there is, you should know that it can produce false negatives, in the sense that you may not find a homotopy equivalence even though one exists. However, it sometimes succeeds (on all examples) in this kind of combinatorial setting, perhaps after a barycentric subdivision or two of the complex, and sometimes it ends up being a tool for proving such statements. (Another less "computation-friendly" tool is Quillen theorem A for posets...)

Comment: @TimCampion There are such posets on 9 elements: take a disjoint union on three chains of 3 elements each. Add covering relations to make the top element of each of the chains larger than the minimum of the other two. So I guess Mare's computation covers at least some examples like this.

Comment: @TimCampion I spent some time thinking about a similar idea last night. It looks useful to think of partitions into $w=\mathrm{width}(P)$ chains (these exist by Dilworth's theorem). It seems the "interesting" examples are ones where at least one union $U$ of a proper subset of the set of chains is dominating (and this should hold for all such partitions of the poset). I think examples with a chain partition of size $w$ which do not satisfy this property always satisfy the conjecture.

Comment: @GevaYashfe Sure, but the example poset you give is not connected, and I think that Mare is only discussing connected posets.

Comment: @TimCampion I think it is connected: The order complex is a union of three triangles (which come from the three chains,) each of which is connected to the other two triangles by a pair of distinct edges (corresponding to the extra covering relations which make the maximum of each chain larger than the minimum of each of the other two).

Answer (score 4):

I made a Sage program to check whether the question has a positive answer for a given graph.

I found no counterexample yet for comparability graphs of posets.
Here is the program to test it for a randomly generated poset:

```
P = posets.RandomPoset(14, 0.3)
display(P)
G = P.comparability_graph();
display(G)
def test_homologygraph(G):
    U = Subsets(G)
    GGU=Set(G)
    T=[t for t in U if G.is_dominating(GGU.difference(t))==true]
    TT=[list(r) for r in T]
    S=SimplicialComplex(TT)
    W=S.homology(base_ring=GF(2))
    tt=len(W)
    F=[dimension(W[t]) for t in [0..tt-1]]
    FF=[r for r in [0..tt-1] if F[r]>0]
    uu=min(FF)
    return(uu+1)

def conjecturetestforperfectgraph(G):
    oo=test_homologygraph(G)
    oo2=G.vertex_cover(value_only=True)
    return(oo==oo2)

display(conjecturetestforperfectgraph(G))
```

But it gave a counterexample for perfect graphs (one with 6 elements). Note that this is not part of the question in this thread but was a suggested in the comments as a generalisation of the question.

```
def test_homologygraph(G):
    U = Subsets(G)
    GGU=Set(G)
    T=[t for t in U if G.is_dominating(GGU.difference(t))==true]
    TT=[list(r) for r in T]
    S=SimplicialComplex(TT)
    W=S.homology(base_ring=GF(2))
    tt=len(W)
    F=[dimension(W[t]) for t in [0..tt-1]]
    FF=[r for r in [0..tt-1] if F[r]>0]
    uu=min(FF)
    return(uu+1)

def conjecturetestforperfectgraph(G):
    oo=test_homologygraph(G)
    oo2=G.vertex_cover(value_only=True)
    return(oo==oo2)
n=6
U=graphs(n)
UU=[g for g in U if g.is_perfect()]
n=len(UU)
UU2=[UU[t] for t in [1..n-1]]
UU3=[g for g in UU2 if conjecturetestforperfectgraph(g)==false]
G=UU3[0]
display(G)
display(conjecturetestforperfectgraph(G))
```

edit: Here a (new) program to test the conjecture for posets with $n$ points:

```
n=7
def test_homologyposet(P):
    G = P.comparability_graph();
    U = Subsets(G)
    GGU=Set(G)
    T=[t for t in U if G.is_dominating(GGU.difference(t))==true]
    TT=[list(r) for r in T]
    S=SimplicialComplex(TT)
    W=S.homology(base_ring=GF(2))
    tt=len(W)
    F=[dimension(W[t]) for t in [0..tt-1]]
    FF=[r for r in [0..tt-1] if F[r]>0]
    uu=min(FF)
    return(uu+1)

def conjecturetestforposet(P):
    G= P.comparability_graph();
    oo=test_homologyposet(P)
    oo2=G.vertex_cover(value_only=True)
    return(oo==oo2)

PP=Posets(n)
PP1=[p for p in PP if len(p)>p.width()+1]
PP2=[p for p in PP1 if conjecturetestforposet(p)==true]
display(PP1==PP2)
```

Here the example for the join of two diamonds with 5 elements:

```
P1=posets.DiamondPoset(5)
P2=posets.DiamondPoset(5)
U=P1.ordinal_sum(P2)
display(U)
def test_homologyposet(P):
    G = P.comparability_graph();
    U = Subsets(G)
    GGU=Set(G)
    T=[t for t in U if G.is_dominating(GGU.difference(t))==true]
    TT=[list(r) for r in T]
    S=SimplicialComplex(TT)
    W=S.homology(base_ring=GF(2))
    tt=len(W)
    F=[dimension(W[t]) for t in [0..tt-1]]
    FF=[r for r in [0..tt-1] if F[r]>0]
    uu=min(FF)
    return(uu+1)

def conjecturetestforposet(P):
    G= P.comparability_graph();
    oo=test_homologyposet(P)
    oo2=G.vertex_cover(value_only=True)
    return(oo==oo2)

display(conjecturetestforposet(U))
```

Here how to calculate the homology over a field K of a given poset P (here a random poset):

```
P = posets.RandomPoset(14, 0.3)
display(P)
G = P.comparability_graph();
display(G)

def posethomology(G,K):
    U = Subsets(G)
    GGU=Set(G)
    T=[t for t in U if G.is_dominating(GGU.difference(t))==true]
    TT=[list(r) for r in T]
    S=SimplicialComplex(TT)
    W=S.homology(base_ring=K)
    return(W)

display(posethomology(G,ZZ))

display(posethomology(G,QQ))

display(posethomology(G,GF(2)))
```

Some random examples revealed that it can happen that there is a unique non-zero degree in which the homology has dimension/rank more than one.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment so I post it as a community wiki answer.

I recently saw a result in the book "Ordered sets" by Schröder and I wonder whether it can be applied when choosing the right point v:
Let $K=(V,S)$ be a (finite always) simplicial complex. Then the link complex $(N(v) \setminus \{v \},Lk(v))$ of a point $v$ is the simplicial complex with $N(v):= \{ w \in V | \{v,w \} \in S \}$ and $Lk(v)= \{ b \in S | \{v\} \cup b \in S , \{v\} \cap b = \emptyset \}$.

Then theorem A.18 in the book states:

> Theorem: Let $K=(V,S)$ be a simplicial complex, $q \geq 1$ and let $v \in V$ be such that $H_q((N(v) \setminus \{v \},Lk(v)))= \{0 \}$. Then the followng hold:

> a) If $q=1$ and $H_0((N(v) \setminus \{v \},Lk(v)))= \mathbb{Z}$, then $H_1(K)=H_1(K [V \setminus \{v \}])$.

> b) If $q \geq 2$ and $H_{q-1}((N(v) \setminus \{v \},Lk(v)))= \{0\}$, then $H_q(K)= H_q(K[V \setminus \{v \}])$.

Corollary A.19 then states :

> Corollary: Let $K(V,S)$ be a simplicial complex and $v \in V$ such that the link complex $(N(v) \setminus \{v \},Lk(v))$ is acyclic. Then, for all $q \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, we have $H_q(K)=H_q(K[V \setminus \{v\}])$.

Maybe someone has an idea for a good choice of $v$ to use induction or another argument that might at least work for certain posets to prove the statement for the comparability graphs (or the alexander dual equivalent statement as in the comment by Geva Yashfe). I will do some computer tests whether such a thing can work.